# Rejected HTTPS password being showing plain-text password in browser

Tags: angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api

We have a web app which is HTML/AngularJS on the front-end and uses MS Web API on the background. We require the use of HTTPS for security reasons. Every article I've read about using plaintext passwords and how to login basically comes down to "just use HTTPS and everything will be secure".

Recently, we were testing the app in-house and the Web API service was accidentally down when the QA person was trying to login. What happened next is what you see in the image below. The password was shown in plain text in the browser. QA, my boss, the company, God and everyone in America is "having a cow" because of this.

The message being displayed in the browser isn't something I coded, it appears that it is part of AngularJS which is trying to do me a favor by showing me a failed API call and what object it was trying to pass to the API. In which case, it makes sense (I think) that Angular has that information.

Can anyone please help me understand what happened here? And what is considered the proper way to address this? I assume I can add some JavaScript code to encrypt the password on the client side first, but that also seems like it would be super easy for a hacker to intercept on the client side. So what's the correct approach to take to keep things secure on the client?

[image]

Comment: HTTPS is basicly HTTP with SSL/TLS which are Transport Layer Protocols. They don't encrypt the data itself - instead the transmission of data is encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

What happened is that the user (you) and the browser (on your machine) live in the same trust boundary.

You just typed that password into the browser. The browser only hides it in the input box to prevent shoulder-surfing. The browser does not really attempt to hide something you just typed in from you.

If you open dev tools in the browser, you can see anything that is sent over the wire in the HTTP protocol. Anyone outside your trust boundary cannot see this because the HTTPS protocol encrypts anything on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

its hard to tell without looking on the code, but I found the similar [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2889) :

```
app.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);
```